# Can 2 conditionals be combined like this?

Tags: jquery

I want to 1)display an alert if ("#one") is checked and ("#two") isn't checked. Then display a different alert if both are checked. What I have does the first part right, then displays both alerts on the second part.

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked") && $("#two").is(":not(:checked)")) {
    alert("foo");
    } else {
        if($(this).is(":checked") && $("#two").is(":checked")) {
            alert("foo foo");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it, I think.

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    var thisIsChecked = this.checked,
        twoisChecked = $('#two').get(0).checked;

    if(thisIsChecked) {
         if (twoisChecked) {
            alert('foo foo');    //  <----
         }                       //      |  note the switch
         else {                  //      |
            alert('foo');        //  <----
         }
    }
});
```

See also: [When to use Vanilla JavaScript vs. jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery)

Comment: can you explain the comma separated variable? and the .get(0) what does that do?

Comment: @Dirty: the comma separated is more-or-less equivalent to separate `var` statements. Some people, like [Douglas Crockford](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), advocate using a single `var` statement per function. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810313/). The [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) call returns the underlying DOM element (not a jQuery element) so that you can access the `.checked` attribute rather than making a more-expensive `.attr()` call when it's just not necessary.

Comment: very good, thanks. I'll try and incorporate this. I really appreciate it man.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       var $two = $("#two");
       if (!$two.is(":checked")) {
            alert("foo");
       } else {
            alert("foo foo");
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me. Example of this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/andypaxo/9vJGL/

Is this the behaviour that you want?

Comment: had a selector wrong, i guess it was ok to begin with. thx @andypaxo!

Comment: @Dirty: you're still making things more complicated (and much less efficient!) than needed, amigo.

Comment: @Matt - I know, man I'm trying. which method is best? I'm familiar with ternary operators, but instead of vanilla alert's I'm using jAlert dialog boxes so those are out.

Comment: @Dirty: ternary operators? Where did [the conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator) come into this?

Comment: in Jordan's example. I'm a little more familiar with those, from PHP and had tried it, but couldn't use my jAlert boxes.

Answer (score 1):

[JSfiddle with solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh6kg/)

HTML:

```
<form>
   <input id="one" type="checkbox" />
   <input id="two" type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
var one = $("#one");
var two = $("#two");

one.click(function() {    
    if (one.is(":checked"))  {
        if (two.is(":checked")) {
           alert("foo foo"); 
        } else {
           alert("foo");
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: trying it out, but I need variables to be local as there will be a lot of these

Comment: You could write it like this, I only make them variables to cache the lookups: `$("#one").click(function() {    
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))  {
        if ($("#two").is(":checked")) {
           alert("foo foo"); 
        } else {
           alert("foo");
        }  
    }
});`

Answer (score 1):

I'd refactor a bit to get rid of the nested ifs and dry things up a bit:

```
$("#one").click(function() {
    if(!this.checked) { return }
    var message = $("#two").is(':checked') ? 'foo foo' : 'foo';
    alert(message)
});
```