# Variable declaration: using var keyword for each variable, or commas?

Tags: javascript, syntax, var, variable-declaration

When declaring variables at the top of a function, is there a difference between those two ways to do so?

```
var firstvar;
var secondvar;
var thirdvar;
```

and

```
var firstvar,
    secondvar, 
    thirdvar;
```

Comment: It's totally up to the developer. AFAIK, there is no significant performance difference as well.

Comment: imo, it's  just a matter of readbility and personal preference. either way works just as well.

Comment: Fyi, I've reworded your question so it can be properly answered in a constructive way.

Comment: thank you both for the feedback and the rewording

Answer (score 5):

Here there is a very well written blog post about [multiple var statements](http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/) vs single ones. I have to say that I mostly agree with Ben Alman: when I started with JS years ago, I used single statement but I switched to multiple statement for maintenance and readability reasons. Of course, I'm still using single var statement where it makes sense (e.g. when I don't have to assign values to those variables and where they are all logically related).

Answer (score 3):

The commonly used static code analysis tool [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) would tell you to combine them all into a single var statement. There is a fair explanation of why this is a good idea in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810313/what-is-the-reason-behind-jslint-saying-there-are-too-many-var-statements).

Answer (score 2):

Try to keep one style the whole code through. It doesn't matter which one.

Answer (score 1):

It's purely a matter of personal preference. Most people seem to use the `var x, y, z` way (with one variable per line) though.

JSLint also [suggests](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#scope) to use only one `var` statement, but the rules of that tool were obviously influenced by its developer's preferences, too.

However, I've seen quite a few auto-indent tools (for example, every single one that is available for Vim) to break in some cases when using multi-variable `var` statements so if that's the case for you, too, you better use separate `var` statements.